# Why does this show errors when it was working

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

*****Code at the bottom*****

Hi, I just got this macro to repair. People tell me that it was working before.
This macro is supposed to copy only the visible filtered data (dynamic tables mainly) and create a new excel file with all the same worksheets but with only the visible data copied and paste in them (worksheets) with no dynamic table. This is meant to reduce the weight of the file but not to make an exact copy.

You are supposed to open this file with the one you want to transfer data and you run the macro in the files you want to copy.

First there were methods errors with `'Sheets(Pages).Select'` (I switched from `.Activate`) and it worked.

After that `'NewBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:BZ500").Select'` were methods errors for range, so I split it in two lines:

```
'NewBook.Sheets(1).activate'
'Range("A1:BZ500").Select'
```

This resolved that error.

After that, there is a name attribution error (like the name is already used) to the line:

```
NewBook.Sheets(1).Name = OldBook.Sheets(Page).Name ( i tried a spy but ieverything was ok) so I decided to write it like NewBook.Sheets(1).Name = OldBook.Sheets(Page).Name + Cstr(Page)
```

It resolved the error but the macro is still not doing what it's meant to:

```
    Set OldBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    
    NewBook.Worksheets(1).Name = "Vide"
    
    OldBook.Activate
    
    For Page = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1
    
    OldBook.Activate
    
    Sheets(Page).Activate
    Sheets(Page).Copy Before:=NewBook.Sheets(1)
    
    NewBook.Activate
    
    NewBook.Sheets(1).Name = OldBook.Sheets(Page).Name
    NewBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:BZ500").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
    Next


End Sub
```

**Below is the one with my corrections:**

```
Sub Fichier_Plat()
    Code_optimizer (True)
    Set OldBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    
    NewBook.Worksheets(1).Name = "Vide"
    
    OldBook.Activate
    
    For Page = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1
    
    OldBook.Activate
    
    Sheets(Page).Activate
    Sheets(Page).Copy Before:=NewBook.Sheets(1)
    
    NewBook.Activate
    
    NewBook.Sheets(1).Name = OldBook.Sheets(Page).Name + CStr(Page)
    NewBook.Sheets(1).Activate
    Range("A1:BZ500").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Next

    Code_optimizer (False)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by giving the original coder a hard slap for not defining the variables/not having 'Option Explicit' at the top of the module, for using `Select` and `Activate` and for hard-coding the range that's to be copied.

Maybe this code would be better?

```
Public Sub Fichier_Plat()
    
    Dim OldBook As Workbook 'Declare your variables!
    Set OldBook = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Dim NewBook As Workbook
    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) 'Create new workbook with a single sheet.

    NewBook.Worksheets(1).Name = "Vide"
    
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim newwrksht As Worksheet
    For Each wrkSht In OldBook.Worksheets 'Look at each sheet in turn.
        Set newwrksht = NewBook.Worksheets.Add
        With newwrksht
            .Name = wrkSht.Name  'Will cause error if one of them is called "Vide". Can use wrksht.Index to get number of sheet.
            wrkSht.Range(wrkSht.Cells(1, 1), LastCell(wrkSht)).Copy
            .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        End With
    Next wrkSht

End Sub

Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Worksheet) As Range

    Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next
    With wrkSht
        LastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
        LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    End With
    
    If LastCol = 0 Then LastCol = 1
    If LastRow = 0 Then LastRow = 1

    Set LastCell = wrkSht.Cells(LastRow, LastCol)

End Function
```

Comment: Wow... Day and night compared to the code that was coded before. It makes a world of difference and it is way more versatile that way. Actually the company I work for depends on interns for the programming

Comment: It won't copy any code that might be in the sheet & don't think it copies conditional formatting or names attached to ranges.